# Runtime error(SIGABRT)

Tags: c++, runtime

I need your help regarding this code; I am getting run time error despite having the right code. I know SIGABRT error is due to excessive memory; can you guys tell me where my code has gone wrong and how to correct it?

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string>
    int count=0;
    int a[1000];
    using namespace std;
    void check(string *str,int p)
    {
        int j=0,i,k;
        int flag=0;
        char *first=new char[p];
        char *last=new char[p];
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
        {
            first[j]=str[i].front();
            last[j]=str[i].back();
            j++;
        }
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
            for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
            if(flag>=2)
            {
                a[count++]=0;
                delete first;
                delete last;
                return;
            }
            if(first[i]==last[k])
                break;
            if(k==j-1)
                flag++;
            }
            if(flag>=2)
            {
                a[count++]=0;
                delete first;
                delete last;
                return;
            }
            if(i==j)
                a[count++]=1;
                delete first;
                delete last;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int t,p;
        cin>>t;
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            cin>>p;
            string *str=new string[p];
            for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
                cin>>str[i];
            check(str,p);
            delete str;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            if(a[i]==0)
                cout<<"\nThe door cannot be opened.";
            else
                cout<<"\nOrdering is possible.";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: SIGABRT does not exclusively mean "excessive memory use". Your code is fairly complex to follow, and there is absolutely no indication what the input strings are that you are using to reproduce the problem [which is likely impacting what the outcome is of your porgram!]

Comment: The solution for the code is to separate the last and first characters of a string which is taken as input.Then cancelling out all the characters that are common in the two arrays that is first and last and if the there are no common characters the flag is incremented which will return incase flag is greater than 2

Answer (score 0):

I belive there is one major problem in your code. You allocate arrays but delete single pointers. For `new []` one should use `delete[]` instead of `delete`. I belive it should solve the error.

Comment: Hey i tried to write the code without dynamic allocation that is just assigning str[100] and first[100] and so on yet i get the error and it either gives sigabrt sigsev

Comment: Could you tell in which line of code you get this error? It could definitelly help

Comment: The problem is solved i used the delete[] to release the memory.Thanks for thr help appreciate it.And this code is related to a problem in codechef.The guys dont provide  the test case nor the error specifications for the code its a rel pain debugging the problems.Do you know any site where i can practice coding properly with proper test cases.Thanks again!!